# Flask forms. How to make variable from views visible in forms.py

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask and WTForms.
I have a view in flask:

```
@app.route('/test/<bar>')
def foo(bar):
    form = SomeForm():
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            query = User(somedata = form.somedata.data,
                         another_data = form.anotherdata.data)
            db.session.add(query)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('ok')
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('test.html', form=form, bar=bar)
```

and a form:

```
#imports here
    class SomeForm(Form):
        ch1 = SomeTable.query.filter_by(age='1').all()
        choice1 = SelectField('Select data', choices=[(e.name, e.name) for e in ch1])
```

I'm need to get variable 'bar' from my view and make it visible in my form to make query with 2 conditions(age and bar) in my select field in form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in `__init__`, not when defining the form class.

```
class SomeForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        ch1 = SomeTable.query.filter_by(bar=bar)
        self.choice1.kwargs['choices'] = tuple((e.name, e.name) for e in ch1)
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in the view:

```
form = SomeForm(bar)
```